# Parallelization of indepedent Do

Tags: parallelization

I'm struggling understanding the syntax for parallel process. I have two Do that are independent and I would like to parallelize them,

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ClearAll[Subscript]
d = 0.95; n = 10; gridl = 0.001; L = Reverse[Range[1, n - 1]];

P[b_, a_] := Module[{p = a/(a + b + 1)},
                While[
   p/(1 - d) < (a/(a + b)) (1 + d*R[[b, a + 1]]) + 
     b/(a + b)*d*R[[b + 1, a]], p = p + gridl;];
  SetPrecision[p, 4]]

R = Table[Subscript[r, b, a], {b, 1, n}, {a, 1, n}];
Do[Subscript[r, x, n] = (n/(n + x))/(1 - d);
 Subscript[r, n, x] = (x/(n + x))/(1 - d), {x, 1, n}]

Do[
 Subscript[r, i, i] = P[i, i]/(1 - d);
 list = Reverse[Range[1, i - 1]];
 Do[Subscript[r, i, x] = P[i, x]/(1 - d), {x, list}]; (***)
 Do[Subscript[r, x, i] = P[x, i]/(1 - d), {x, list}], {i, L}]
```

I would like the two Do at (***) to go in parallel of each other. They fills the column and row of the table given the initial position in the diagonal and they are independent of each other (the do themself are sequential since they need previous values).

I checked similar questions ([sol1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153515/force-parallelization-on-this-cell?rq=1), [sol2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250350/parallelization-of-two-procedures-inside-module?rq=1)), but I can't make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read this to better understand when parallelization is useful in Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/12 You are trying to assign to the same symbol from two parallel processes. This is not possible, as Mathematica uses distributed memory parallelization. Yes, you can create the _illusion_ of being able to modify the same symbol from parallel processes using `SetSharedVariable`, but the mechanisms that are used to make this work in the background will make the parallel version slower than the serial one.

Comment: As an alternative, you could look into [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html): there may be no need to pre-compute values in a `Do` loop. Concretely, if you [get away from using `Subscript`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/871/26598) and say `r[x_, n_] := r[x, n] = (n/(n + x))/(1 - d)` etc., everything may get much simpler for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Speeding up a bad algorithm by parallelization is rarely a good idea. Let's work on the algorithm instead.

Firstly, using `SetPrecision` inside the calculation may slow down the code. Just run it natively with machine precision, and truncate/round the results after finishing the calculation.

The function $P$ can be defined through the [`Ceiling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ceiling.html) function, which should be much faster than using a `While` loop, especially if `gridl` is very small. Also, it shows how to take the continuum limit (`gridl = 0`) by removing the `Ceiling` function.

```
d = 0.95; n = 10; gridl = 0.001;
P[b_, a_] := a/(a + b + 1) +
             Ceiling[(1 - d)/(a + b) (a (1 + d r[b, a + 1]) +
                     b d r[b + 1, a]) - a/(a + b + 1), gridl]
```

From there we can define $r$ with a [memoizing function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html):

```
r[x_, n] := r[x, n] = n/((n + x) (1 - d))
r[n, x_] := r[n, x] = x/((n + x) (1 - d))
r[i_, x_] := r[i, x] = P[i, x]/(1 - d)
```

Now simply build a table and let Mathematica figure out how to do it in detail:

```
Table[r[a, b], {a, n}, {b, n}] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 10.0867 & 13.42 & 15.08 & 16.0733 & 16.7257 & 17.18 & 17.5356 & 17.8 & 18.0036 & 18.1818 \\
 6.76 & 10.08 & 12.08 & 13.4086 & 14.36 & 15.0533 & 15.6 & 16.0255 & 16.38 & 16.6667 \\
 5.08 & 8.06667 & 10.0714 & 11.5 & 12.5711 & 13.4 & 14.0473 & 14.5733 & 15.0062 & 15.3846 \\
 4.07333 & 6.73429 & 8.64 & 10.0689 & 11.18 & 12.0691 & 12.7867 & 13.3677 & 13.8571 & 14.2857 \\
 3.39714 & 5.78 & 7.56667 & 8.96 & 10.0709 & 10.98 & 11.7292 & 12.3486 & 12.88 & 13.3333 \\
 2.9 & 5.04444 & 6.72 & 8.05273 & 9.13333 & 10.0508 & 10.82 & 11.4667 & 12.01 & 12.5 \\
 2.54222 & 4.48 & 6.03455 & 7.30667 & 8.37231 & 9.27143 & 10.0333 & 10.7 & 11.2682 & 11.7647 \\
 2.26 & 4.03636 & 5.48 & 6.69385 & 7.72286 & 8.6 & 9.37 & 10.0318 & 10.6 & 11.1111 \\
 2.01818 & 3.65333 & 5.01538 & 6.17429 & 7.16667 & 8.02 & 8.77529 & 9.42889 & 10.0137 & 10.5263 \\
 1.81818 & 3.33333 & 4.61538 & 5.71429 & 6.66667 & 7.5 & 8.23529 & 8.88889 & 9.47368 & 10. \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you @user2574698 ?

```
Do[Subscript[r, i, i] = P[i, i]/(1 - d);
 list = Reverse[Range[1, i - 1]];
 ParallelDo[Subscript[r, x, i] = P[x, i]/(1 - d); 
  Subscript[r, i, x] = P[i, x]/(1 - d), {x, list}],
 {i, L}
```

Notice the ";" within the compound expressions in the Do.

If you are a beginner to Mathematica, it is good idea to try to use functional programming rather than procedural programing.  It takes a while if you are coming from a language like Python, but I think you will learn to enjoy trying a different programming paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not work. The issue is that each Do needs the previous value within to compute the next one, so ParallelDo fail to fill the matrix R.